# Identifying the range of the voice

Tags: sound

I'm trying to do an equalization in an audio program called Audition.

To have a good voice equalization, I need to have a frequency range of my voice.

A minimum value and a maximum frequency value.

It does not have to be very precise, but I need to have an idea where to work correcting my voice.

The link to the audio is this (If someone is having trouble accessing the file, let me know):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N3vQzsB1t222JXB2Sxze9yycEJdyHH2Y/view?usp=drivesdk

```
a = Audio@"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N3vQzsB1t222JXB2Sxze9yycEJdyHH2Y/view?usp=drivesdk";
Column[{AudioPlot@a, AudioPlot@AudioTrim@a}]
```

Is there a function that does this?

Comment: Spectrogram will give you an idea of the frequency range...

Comment: I will see. [Spectrogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spectrogram.html)

Comment: Try `Periodogram[a]`